# Angular: How to conditionally apply a style by using Date Pipe in the condition?

Tags: angular

I have an array in my `component.ts` and I want to loop in it in my `component.html` then inside that array contain a date, so with data I want to run a condition, if that date is greater than the current date then apply a specific style, if not then apply another style. For example something like this:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div *ngFor="let t of table; let i = index">
    <div [ngStyle]="{'background-color': t.date > | t:today ? 'red' : 'green'}">
      <ul class="otherStyle">
        <li>{{t.name}}</li>
        <span>{{t.date}}</span>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's a little confusing what you asked, btw as general you don't need pipe in your expression

Comment: hmm, I think it's a bit confusing as you said, but here what I want, I have an array in my component.ts and I want to loop in it in my compoenent.html then inside that array contain a date, so with data I want to run a condition, if that date is greater than the current date then apply a specific style, if not then apply another style...I hope it's clear now

Comment: Ye you definetly do not need the pipe for that. Use plain date objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have an array of dates:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  dates = ['2018-12-19', '2018-12-20', '2018-12-22'];
  todayDate = new Date();
}
```

And your template:

```
<div class="container">
   <div *ngFor="let d of dates; let i = index">
        <div [ngStyle]="{'background-color':  (d | date:today) > (todayDate | date:today) ? 'green' : 'red'}">
            <ul class="otherStyle">
                <li>{{d |date:today}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Here is an example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xirdss)

Comment: I was already working on this solution, but you came with it before me!! :D thank you!!