# Conditional style in Angular 1.5 based on comparing dates

Tags: angular, date, compare, conditional-statements, styling

I'm trying to compare a Angular list element (task.task_deadline_date) to todays date and bold the date if it is today or later (before today to remain regular font). I've tested the below syntax but I think the issue is the comparing the dates, is there a way to set the formats consistent?

```
<td 
  class="min-wth-100" 
  ng-style="{'font-weight':(task.task_deadline_date >= new Date()) ? 'bold' : '' }"
>
  {{::task.task_deadline_date}}
</td>
```

I've tried the method at the link below, but trying to adapt it to a one-line vs having to add code to the controller. Not sure if the pipe is a way to set the date formats consistently?

[Angular: How to conditionally apply a style by using Date Pipe in the condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53890229/angular-how-to-conditionally-apply-a-style-by-using-date-pipe-in-the-condition)

Answer (score 0):

Compare Date Like This It will Return true/false

```js
let task_deadline_date = '2012-03-19T07:22Z';

console.log(new Date(task_deadline_date) >= new Date())
```

// In Your Case new Date(task.task_deadline_date) >= new Date()

Comment: Interesting, your code works in the console but not in my html '<td class="min-wth-100" ng-style="{'font-weight':(new Date(task.task_deadline_date) >= new Date() ? 'bold' : '' }">{{::task.task_deadline_date}}</td>' gives the following error

Comment: main.min.js:1 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'Date' is unexpected, expecting [)] at column 21 of the expression [{'font-weight':(new Date(task.task_deadline_date) >= new Date() ? 'bold' : '' }] starting at [Date(task.task_deadline_date) >= new Date() ? 'bold' : '' }].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$parse/syntax?p0=Date&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B)%5D&p2=21&p3=%7B'font-weight'%3A(new%20Date(task.task_deadline_date)%20%3E%3D%20new%20Date()%20%3F%20'bold'%20%3A%20''%20%7D&p4=Date(task.task_deadline_date)%20%3E%3D%20new%20Date()%20%3F%20'bold'%20%3A%20''%20%7D

Comment: apply this logic in ts file and pass simply that variable to it

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a function to the controller script:

```
rept.checkDate = function(date) {
          return new Date(date) >= new Date();
        };
```

Then changing HTML to:

```
<td class="min-wth-100" ng-style="rept.checkDate('{{task.task_deadline_date}}') && {'font-weight':'bold'} || {'font-weight':''}">{{::task.task_deadline_date}}</td>
```

Was hoping for a one line option, but oh well. Thanks for the help.